# Difference between Point Sprites and Billboards

Tags: point-sprites

Can someone tell me the difference between Point Sprites and Billboards in OpenGL? I read a lot about both of them and I'm getting confused more and more about when to use which of them and whether there is actually a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia only knows about [Sprites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics)) ([Billboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_(computer_graphics)) redirects there):

> In computer graphics, a sprite is a two-dimensional bitmap that is integrated into a larger scene, most often in a 2D video game. Originally, the term sprite referred to fixed-sized objects composited together, by hardware, with a background.[3](https://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/%7Ee20068/teaching/i3dg&a/2012/lecture9.html) Use of the term has since become more general.

One [source](https://titan.csit.rmit.edu.au/%7Ee20068/teaching/i3dg&a/2012/lecture9.html) states:

**Sprite**

> A sprite is the traditional term given to a 2D image displayed in a game

**Billboard**

> ... you need to re-orient each particle so that it's facing the viewer.
> This technique of re-orienting the sprites is called billboarding.

Another [source](https://www.geeks3d.com/20140807/billboarding-vertex-shader-glsl/):

> Billboarding is a popular technique used in 3D graphics programming.
> Billboarding allows an object (usually a quad) to always face a given
> camera. Here are some common uses of billboarding:
>
> – particles – halo surrounding an object – trees rendering
>
> For the particular case of particles, the billboarding is a GPU
> built-in feature when point-sprites are used (a single point is
> transformed to a billboarded quad).

Yet [another](http://myst.dustbird.net/wiki/Sprites_and_Billboards) states that both face the camera, but billboards only rotate about their vertical axis (think trees).

Some references specifically for [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL):

- https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Rendering-Sprites
- https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Particles (billboarding)
- https://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/

Live Examples by [Three.js](https://threejs.org/)/[WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) (though I can't tell the difference):

- https://threejs.org/examples/?q=billboard#webgl_points_billboards
- https://threejs.org/examples/?q=sprite#webgl_points_sprites